# Changing Screen Resolution and Finding Gamma Values

Tags: display-resolution

I'm brand new to Linux and Ubuntu, but since I just completed a computer build I decided to try it and see how I like it.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on an Intel i5 4690k and an EVGA GTX960 if those matter.  I just started it up and I cannot figure out how to change the screen size.  I've been looking through the tutorials and I've attempted to create a screen resolution and change that to mine, but when I put in the command
"xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync"
as I've seen on other helps, it gives me the message
"xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default"
Since I am new to this I don't know how to input the Gamma of the output device.  Thanks everyone